# A question on notation used in differential equations by George F Simmons

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, notation

[image]In page number 57 of Differential Equations by George F Simmons a rather peculiar notation is used in the section on integrating factors, that is when he talks about a method of reducing to exact differential equation, it goes like this in equation (11) $$d(\dfrac{y}{x}) = \dfrac{xdy-ydx}{x^2}$$ What is it? It looks like the quotient rule but it doesnt really make sense to me.

Comment: It is the quotient rule $\frac{d}{dx}\frac{f}{g}$ with $g(x) = x$.

Comment: But why is it written as d(y/x)?

Comment: Because it's written as a differential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the quotient rule, packaged as a total differential
$$
dF =\partial_xF\,dx+\partial_yF\,dy
$$
of the function $$
F(x,y)=\frac yx
$$
to get
$$
dF=-\frac{y}{x^2}\,dx +\frac{1}x\,dy=...
$$

Comment: Great i get it now , thank you